# How to access infos in protobuf response from dialogflow API

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I am having serious trouble accessing the values from a protobuf object I receive after accessing the google dialogflow api

```
(... create google cloud session object ...)

text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
response = session_client.detect_intent(request={"session": session, "query_input": query_input})

from google.protobuf import json_format
response_json = json_format.MessageToDict(response)
```

The error is:

`AttributeError: 'MapComposite' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'`

Basically I have two issues:

a) I am not able to convert the protobuf to json (here I am easily able to see how to access the infos I am looking for)

b) I am not able to understand the protobof data structure. Is there a dictionary?

Any helper in a) or b) are appreciated.

btw: I am looking for a way to access `response.parameters` in the API response.

---

**Edit for Scott:**

response.parameters is an object:
<proto.marshal.collections.maps.MapComposite object at 0x7fe7323f7da0>

The parameters object is described here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse#QueryResult

Does it make sense to you? Because I don't understand how to access the values in this object.

Comment: Hi OP, can you explain more on what you are trying to access when you say "response.parameters"? Are you pertaining to Parameter References of the Intent's response or are you pertaining to something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `MessageToDict` approach, as shown below, to serialize protobuf to a dictionary and use `response._pb` instead of `response`.

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
response_json = MessageToDict(response._pb)
```

Now, you can now navigate through the dictionary for the `parameters` that you want to access as shown below since `parameters` is inside/under `queryResult` (based on the structure).

```
print(response_json["queryResult"]["parameters"])
```